# How can I stop `vmmem` process?

Tags: windows-10, docker, virtual-memory

I installed docker on windows home which uses WSL2 as a backend. However, ever since I installed a new  container on it yesterday my computer fan has been turning on every 5 seconds. I am not sure what is overloading the computer. Vmmem is only using 0.1% of my CPU, but since it is using 1 GB of memory, that might be the source of the problem. I ran docker stop $(docker ps -aq) to stop my only running container, but it made no difference. What should I do?

Comment: The Microsoft vmmem process represents the memory used by your virtual machines.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180717-00/?p=99265#:~:text=The%20vmmem%20process%20is%20a,of%20memory%20and%20CPU%20resources.   You need to look at Task Manager to see what is using CPU.

Comment: I know that Vmmem is using 0.1% of my CPU because I looked at Task Manager. Overall, only 3% of my CPU is being used and 46% of my memory. So I think most resources are going towards the memory.

Comment: Your fan should not turn on at 3% CPU.  Keep Task Manager open and watch when the fan turns on.

Comment: I have task manager open and the fan is turning on at 3% CPU. Sometimes even at 2% CPU.

Comment: The only way to stop vmmem from running is to stop all the virtual machines. Are you sure docker and WSL are compliant with Windows Home?  I did not think so.

Comment: I have a Windows 10 Pro (Insider) machine. I started up Kali in Hyper-V. Vmmem  is running but the fan is not running high or unusually. How did you get docker and WSL running in Home?

Answer (score 27):

As found on the relevant [WSL issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8529):

You can't kill Vmmem, but you can kill the WSL service and let it restart. In an admin terminal, run:

```
$ taskkill /f /im wslservice.exe
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Other answers that suggest using wsl.exe don't work when wsl isn't responding.

Comment: Process "wslservice.exe" not found for me.

Comment: @dermoritz Some people have also reported that in the linked issue - no clue why you don't have that service, but you could try killing `wsl.exe` instead.

Answer (score 15):

You can shutdown the "VMMEM-process" by running

```
wsl --shutdown
```

via <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or in your commandline/terminal.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've already tried shutting down every VM, even completely killed docker, and still vmmem is using up 100% CPU.

Comment: When I tried this in a Powershell admin window, the command just hung until I ran `taskkill /f /im wslservice.exe` in a different window.

Comment: worked fine for me (without admin). taskkill not

Answer (score 3):

Only way to stop the vmmemwsl process seems to be to restart Windows. You will get access denied if you try and stop the process.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1174127)

Comment: I added some more context to make it answer the question more clearly

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer :-(   At least in my case. wsl --shutdown doesn't do anything. (Linux as main OS is much less pain.)

Answer (score 3):

Close Docker and after a while the VmmemWSL process will end.

[image: QuitDockerDesktopImg]

Comment: it seems to me that this is not always true

Answer (score 3):

As of **2023** the only thing that worked for me was:

1. Press the combination: *Windows key + R*
2. Type *services.msc* and press OK
3. Scroll down to Hyper-V services
   [image: List of Hyper-V services]
4. Right Click > Stop
5. If you right click > properties you can configure the startup type (in my case 'disabled').

[image: Service property settings]

The one that did it for me was Hyper-V virtual machine management. Repeat the steps 1-5 with as many services as needed.

In order to verify if it really worked, go to Start > Resource monitor > 'Memory' tab and see if vmmem.exe is still present (for me it was at the top of the list occupying 500MB).

Comment: You actually need to stop "vmcompute" service as well, as that's the parent service that spawns the VMMEMWSL processes

Answer (score 0):

Execute command prompt in administrator mode and as @retober said:

> You can shutdown the "VMMEM-process" by running

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Otherwise it will get stuck